# JavaFX PropertyValueFactory bind TableView with other controls

Tags: database, binding, javafx, controls, tableview

**Hi everynone,**

I just have a simple question on a correct way database binding implementation.

I got a TableView populated by a database. The database create "Inputs" javaFX POJO objects and pass it to the Tableview.

On a first need I have to link an 'ID' to the TableView data's. The only way I succeed that was by adding an hidden column. But is there a better way to achieve that (TableView <> Id Database binding) without creating an hidden column ?

A second need is to display an Inputs' data that is a LONG VARCHAR and I wan't to display it on a TextArea behind the TableView. This TexArea data should be binded to the TableView's "Inputs" JavaFX POJO objects for add/update/save actions.

Is there a correct way to achieve that without using hidden columns and binding theses columns to other controls or is this the only way to do that ?

If it is the only way is there a possiblity to remove the hidden TableColumns from the TableView menu set by this method ? "tableView.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true)"

A solution could be like this code below but I wanted to know if it is a good/best practice and if it is a common implementation or not and if there is another way without using an Hidden column to bind two controls:

```
inputsTable.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
              @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                  if (mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
                    if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 1) {
                        Inputs input= inputsTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                       if(input != null){  
                           colNote.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(input.noteProperty());
                           colNote.setText("");
                        }
                       colNote.textProperty().bindBidirectional(input.noteProperty());

                  }
                }
              }
            });
```

Here is the view to help understanding:
[image: Main UI]
Thank you for reading me, if you need some sample code I can add some...

**Thanks All, Regards.**

**[EDIT] I think it is a false problem in fact**; when I pass Inputs'POJO to the Tableview the Objects have the ID set so I just need to do a `inputsTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getId()` to retrieve the ID. Or another way would be binding an Observable Integer that would be accessible by the whole application and setted in the `inputsTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Inputs>() {....}` event... **Thanks all, Regards.**

Comment: you can use `col.setVisible(false);`  You also don't even have to add it to the TableView if you never need it.  I don't really understand the rest of the question.  For binding to a TextArea I just posted a small example of binding to a TextField http://stackoverflow.com/a/23015947/2855515

Comment: Hi Brian, Thank you for your post it's responding to my second question. I have implemented it by myself but it is better using JavaFX binding class :-) When I was trying the binding it was unsuccessfull because I was binding the tableView getselectedItem's property rather than using directly the "old/new" properties' objects...  Your post is usefull; Many Thanks, Regards.